# Refresh inner RecyclerView elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a vertical RecyclerView and each element of it, is a nested horizontal RecyclerView. Both have their Adapter and ViewHolder. When I change a flag, I want to be able to refresh the drawing of all items in each inner horizontal RecyclerView. I've written a method in the outer adapter that consequently call the inner one:

OuterAdapter:

```
public void setEditEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    innerAdapter.setEditEnabled(enabled);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

InnerAdapter:

```
public void setEditEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.editable = enabled;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in the activity I call:

```
outerAdapter.setEditEnabled(editable);
outerRecyclerView.invalidate();
```

But only some "rows" are correctly updated...How can I solve this?

EDIT: so the flow is:

Outer setEditEnabled -> inner setEditEnabled -> inner notify -> outer notify

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you calling invalidate on the `RecyclerView`. when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, it automatically updates the `RecyclerView` items. And why is there only one inner Adapter. I think there should be a different adapter for each horizontal RecyclerView.

Comment: Without invalidate I've no effect at all. I've one inner adapter per each horizontal RecyclerView.

Comment: then how are you notifying each adapter. 
Is this method

```public void setEditEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    innerAdapter.setEditEnabled(enabled);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}``` 
 in the ViewHolder of the vertical recyclerview?

Comment: and I have worked with such a situation before. and I never called ```invalidate()```

Comment: yes, the method is inside the vertical RecyclerView adapter, I've edited my question trying to be more clear. Note that the inner adapter method is called from the outer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm doing it right, but it seems to work fine.
Previously I was instantiating a new innerAdapter in the ViewHolder constructor:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RecyclerView innerRecyclerView;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        [...] // init things

        innerRecyclerView.setAdapter(new InnerAdapter(context, onItemClickListener));
    }
}
```

Now I'm doing the new in the OuterAdapter constructor and saving the reference as private field of the class:

```
public DailyMenusAdapter(Context context, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
     innerAdapter = new InnerAdapter(context, onItemClickListener);
}
```

Then I pass the reference to:

```
innerRecyclerView.setAdapter(innerAdapter);
```

Is that ok in your opinion? So reusing the same adapter over and over again.

Answer (score -1):

You know, I think if you will create annonimous Adapter class instead of notifyDataSetChanged (somethink like mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(this, listOfDataYouPass))) it will work fine.
EDIT:Usually we do something  like this to set adapter to RecyclerView:

```
  List mLogs = new ArrayList<>;
    mLogs.addAll (logs);
    mLogAdapter = new LogAdapter(this, mLogs);
     mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.log_list);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mLogAdapter);
```

and then, when we need to modify something we call `mLogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged.` Or just call notifyDataSetChanged inside Adapter class. But in many cases it works wrong, hard to say why in your case.
So here is what I advise:
instead of call notifyDataSetChanged make this method and call it when you need to update or change something:

```
private void updateRecyclerView (){
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new LogAdapter(this, mLogs));
    }
```

Note: Do not pay attention to the names, I took code from the first project I got

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your answer, could you please be more clear? Where should I create a new adapter, in the inner or outer RecyclerView? Could you write some code? Thanks.

Comment: @Jumpa i suggest to use this method for both RecyclerViews